# Upsert huge amount of data by EFCore.BulkExtensions

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework-core, efcore.bulkextensions

I'm using below extension function to Upsert data with EF Core with `EFCore.BulkExtensions`, but the issue is the execution for this function when I tried to insert  2 millions record is taking around 17 minutes and lately it throws this exception

> Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.SORT temporary run storage:  140737501921280' in database 'tempdb' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.\r\nThe transaction log for database 'tempdb' is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION' and the holdup lsn is (41:136:347)

I can see the storage for "C" partition is decreasing when I executed this function:

[image]

When I restart SQL Server, the free space becomes around 30 GB, I tried to use multi threading (parallel) with the insert with no noticed time change, so what do you recommend or is there any issue in the code shown here.

**Note:** the for loop is not taking too much time even if it was 2 millions records.

```
public static async Task<OperationResultDto> AddOrUpdateBulkByTransactionAsync<TEntity>(this DbContext _myDatabaseContext, List<TEntity> data) where TEntity : class
{
    using (var transaction = await _myDatabaseContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
    {
        try
        {
            _myDatabaseContext.Database.SetCommandTimeout(0);

            var currentTime = DateTime.Now;

            // Disable change tracking
            _myDatabaseContext.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

            // Set CreatedDate and UpdatedDate for each entity
            foreach (var entity in data)
            {
                var createdDateProperty = entity.GetType().GetProperty("CreatedDate");

                if (createdDateProperty != null && (createdDateProperty.GetValue(entity) == null || createdDateProperty.GetValue(entity).Equals(DateTime.MinValue)))
                {
                    // Set CreatedDate only if it's not already set
                    createdDateProperty.SetValue(entity, currentTime);
                }

                var updatedDateProperty = entity.GetType().GetProperty("UpdatedDate");

                if (updatedDateProperty != null)
                {
                    updatedDateProperty.SetValue(entity, currentTime);
                }
            }

            // Bulk insert or update
            var updateByProperties = GetUpdateByProperties<TEntity>();

            var bulkConfig = new BulkConfig()
            {
                UpdateByProperties = updateByProperties,
                CalculateStats = true,
                SetOutputIdentity = false
            };

            // Batch size for processing
            int batchSize = 50000;

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i += batchSize)
            {
                var batch = data.Skip(i).Take(batchSize).ToList();
                await _myDatabaseContext.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(batch, bulkConfig);
            }

            // Commit the transaction if everything succeeds
            await transaction.CommitAsync();

            return new OperationResultDto
            {
                OperationResult = bulkConfig.StatsInfo
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exceptions and roll back the transaction if something goes wrong
            transaction.Rollback();
            return new OperationResultDto
            {
                Error = new ErrorDto
                {
                    Details = ex.Message + ex.InnerException?.Message
                }
            };
        }
        finally
        {
            // Re-enable change tracking
            _myDatabaseContext.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is beacuse of long transaction. Transaction log file become very big. Try to do that without transaction. It should work faster.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv and how can I rollback in case any issue occurs during the upsertion process ?

Comment: I don't know nature of your data. If you want simple revert - increase disk drive size. Or invent something idempotent, some flags in records that tey are not confirmed yet. Anyway for 2 million records any operation in transaction needs a huge storage space (DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT). SQL Server makes copy of recorfs for rollback.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I've removed the transaction, yet the C partition is still filling up dramatically.

Comment: There might be an outer transaction somewhere. Use `CalculateStats = false` and don't batch it manually, instead set a batchsize on the config.

Comment: It is needs analysis, if you have batch 50000 records, thses records are copied to `tempdb`, then using `MERGE` they are applied to real table.